# Error in NextMethod("[<-") : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

I have a zoo class data set loaded into R and I am trying to run a `for` loop. But I keep running into the error

> Error in NextMethod("[<-") : subscript out of bounds.

The loop is pretty simple

```
startobs=5
for (i in startobs:(NROW(data)-startobs)) {
  data[startobs+i,"dummy"]=startobs+i

}
```

I think the problem is in the `startobs+i`. R doesn't seem to like placing the index of the loop (`i`) in the `data[i,]`, as your going through each element. What am I doing wrong?

---

The structure of the data is as follows

```
>data

     obs     date   weight  dummy
      1   2010-10-04 52495   NA 
      2   2010-10-01 53000   NA 
      3   2010-09-30 52916   NA 
      4   2010-09-29 52785   NA 
      5   2010-09-28 53348   NA 
      6   2010-09-27 52885   NA 
      7   2010-09-24 52174   NA 
      8   2010-09-23 51461   NA 
      9   2010-09-22 51286   NA 
      10  2010-09-21 50968   NA 
      11  2010-09-20 49250   NA
```

and

```
>dput(head(data))
structure(c(100, 101.01, 110.75, 111.24, 104.96, 104.95, 104.06, 
109.08, 113.48, 111.6, 108, 107.95, 95.96, 100.5, 109.05, 103.57, 
103.88, 104.66, 100.34, 108.31, 109.4, 104.87, 106, 107.91, 22351900, 
11428600, 9137200, 7631300, 4598900, 3551000, 100.34, 108.31, 
109.4, 104.87, 106, 107.91, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = 6:7, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("weight", "height", "BMI", "Age", "Age2", "Intr", 
    "Chol")), index = structure(c(12649, 12650, 12653, 12654, 
12655, 12656), class = "Date"), class = "zoo")
```

Comment: Why is the dummy variable called `dummyvariable` in the for loop, called `dummy` in the display, and entirely absent in the `dput`?

Comment: Also, why are you doing `length(data)` (which is 48) rather than `NROW(data)` (which is 6)? What are you actually trying to do in the loop?

Comment: Sorry made the edits. I am just trying to loop through each of the elements in the "dummy" variable and place a value, the value will vary based on conditional if statements. I removed the if statements because they weren't the problem. It was the startobs+i portion of the code. Is there anyway to loop through each element/observation in the dataset?

Comment: Yes, but `dput(head(data))` still doesn't match up at all with the data you're showing (there are new columns "weight", "BMI", etc). Did you `dput` the wrong dataframe?

Comment: I think you just want to do `for (i in 1:NROW(data)) { data[i, "dummy"] = i }`. This could be done much more easily and efficiently as `data[, "dummy"] = 1:NROW(data)`, but I know this is just a toy example. However, whatever you're trying to do will probably be done better using a vectorized solution rather than a for loop. Perhaps you can share what your goal is?

Comment: Hi David, yes I left those variables out, if I included all the variables in the dataset they wouldn't fit. Nevertheless, they really don't matter for the problem I am trying to solve. So I truncated the data for visual purposes.

Comment: But it's not just that variables are missing- there are also brand new variables of `obs`, `date`, and (most importantly) `dummy`. And the weights are on an entirely different scale (~52000 rather than ~100). Why use `dput` at all if the only thing shared between the `dput` and the rest of the question is the name of a single column?

Comment: Sorry for the frustration but I think your first suggestion solved it. For some reason the "length(data)-startobs" wasn't working. But then I used NROW as you said "NROW(data)-startobs" and then it worked. That's so odd. NROW and length, should be exactly the same. Why is that?

Comment: `length` and `NROW` are never the same (except on trivial examples like a 1x1 matrix). For matrices, `length` gets you the number of cells (`length(matrix(1:100, ncol=20)) == 100`) and for data frames, `length` gets you the number of columns `length(as.data.frame(matrix(1:100, ncol=20))) == 20`.

Comment: Incidentally, if you share your goal (what you're trying to fill the column with) I'd be happy to help you find a vectorized solution (which is both more compact and more computationally efficient than a for loop)

Comment: If you put `browser()` inside your `for` loop, you'll be able to go through your function step-by-step, inspecting objects along the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean to do:

```
for (i in 1:NROW(data)) {
    data[i, "dummy"] = i
}
```

However, whatever you're trying to do in a for loop will probably be easier with a vectorized solution, such as one using `ifelse`.

Comment: @Arun: See the comments on the question above (I also note this is identical to `1:nrow(data)`. The OP notes this is just a toy example and that some other calculation is going in the for loop (so I provided this to explain how the toy example would work). I was noting, both in the comments and my answer, that a vectorized solution was probably superior.